# Java proxy - fetch outgoing request

Tags: java, proxy, javafx

It may be a common question, but:
I've app, which is making request to
**elldmess.cz/api/...**
But this api has gone.
Now I want "something", that **catch** request to *elldmess.cz/api*, reformat it and send it to
**api.elldmess.cz**
*note, it has another format - from URI request to JSONbased, so
simple redirecting won't work*
I've thought about some proxy, which **wrap** old application and remake request.
App is desktop, JavaFX based.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be interested in [AspectJ](http://eclipse.org/aspectj/). This enables you to catch the method calls which make the request to the original site and alter or completely replace them.

Comment: Main thing is, that I cannot modify original code. I've access only to binary classes (also can't dedompile/recompile). Is it still possible? - thanks for reply

Comment: @EllesmessGlain I have never tried it that way, but I think so. Altough You have to know the method signatures you would like to "capture", and AspectJ can use bytecode manipulation during class load time to include your code ([load time weaving](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/devguide/ltw.html))

Comment: Ou yeah!! That was shot in black (I'm Czech, sorry :)). AspectJ works, thanks very much :)